# JavaScript to fire event when a key pressed on the Ajax Toolkit Combo box

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I have the following drop down list which is using the Ajax Toolkit to provide a combo box:

```
<cc1:ComboBox ID="txtDrug" runat="server" style="font-size:8pt; width:267px;" 
            Font-Size="8pt" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" 
            AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" AutoPostBack="True" 
            ontextchanged="txtDrug_TextChanged" />
```

Now I need to load this up with approx 7,000 records which takes a considerable time, and effects the response times when the page is posted back and forth.

The code which loads these records is as follows:

```
dtDrugs = wsHelper.spGetAllDrugs();

txtDrug.DataValueField = "pkDrugsID";
txtDrug.DataTextField = "drugName";
txtDrug.DataSource = dtDrugs;
txtDrug.DataBind();
```

However if I could get an event to fire when a letter is typed instead of having to load 7000 records it is reduced to less than 50 in most instances.

I think this can be done in JavaScript. So the question is how can I get an event to fire such that when the form starts there is nothing in the drop down, but as soon as a key is pressed it searches for those records starting with that letter.

The .Net side of things I'm sure about - it is the JavaScript I'm not.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the AutoComplete extender applies because it is only for TextBox and not ComboBox. I believe Paul need to be able to retrieve the ID of the item selected, thing that a TextBox cannot provide.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [AutoComplete extender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) attached to a TextBox, you need to set following properties to provide data source for the extender:

```
ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
```

Where *AutoComplete.asmx* is link to your service and *GetCompletionList* is your service method to call, the signature of this method must match the following:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public string[]
GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count) 
{ ... }
```